# Aweber form not collecting leads because of simple jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aweber

I have a signup form that is having trouble to pass the input fiel data to aweber list.

submission takes place in same window without reloading the page, and I can see in the bottom of the browser window how the server is connecting to aweber url but the data is not passing through:

html form code that I am currently using:

```
<iframe id="AweberFormSubmitFrame" style="display: none" name="AweberFormSubmitFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" class="firstFom" target="AweberFormSubmitFrame" id="formularioaweber">
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="79676xxxx"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="tizona_prosp"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="#" id="redirect_060b3473249d14423a8ed1bb376cdca8"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Tizona_Joyas_Prospectos"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="email"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value=""/> 
    <div class="emailinput" >
        <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="awf_field-44988808" placeholder="Ingrese Su Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="submitinput">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="enviar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, this is the code that is changing some styling after the form is submitted:

```
$(function (){
    $( "#formularioaweber" ).submit(function( event ) {
        //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        //alert($('input#awf_field-44988808').val());
        var a = $('#awf_field-44988808').val();
        $("#success-message").removeClass('display-none');
        // alert(a);
        $('#awf_field-44988808').val('');
        $('#enviar').css({"background-color": "grey"});
        $('#enviar').val('PROCESADO');
        $('#enviar').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#awf_field-44988808').attr('placeholder', 'Catalogo enviado a '+a);
        $("#awf_field-44988808").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
});
```

I believe this happens because the form fields get reseted before the connection is stablished with aweber.com, this is just my guess.

Note: if I omit the jquery code, the form works fine.

Comment: the [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) is executed before the form is submitted to the server to allow you to validate and reject submission if needed.

Comment: Can you illustrate me on how to submit the form data before the submit event takes place ?

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169471/is-there-an-after-submit-jquery-option)

Comment: I added a setTimeout approach and it works perfect.